# Can't properly connect MYSQL with Django settings.py

Tags: mysql, django

I've checked that I have a live mysql server, database created, and ran pip freeze to ensure that mysqlclient is installed.The only error I see is that Mysqlclient isn't connected but I can see that mysqlclient==1.4.6 is installed and is in my requirement.txt file.

**I am running in a virtual environment

My settings.py is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'bradynce_crm',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
 }
}
```

I try to run the server and get this error:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d5271f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: It may be that you have more than single Python on your machine - you can go to django shell by running `python3 manage.py shell` and type in `import mysqlclient` to see if it's indeed installed. Also, try using `'HOST': 'localhost',` if your ip is not 127.0.0.1

Comment: I just ran it and it says 'No module named mysqlclient'. So you may be right, but how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: So make sure you run `pip3 install mysqlclient` in the same Python environment and django and verify if it's installed, then it should be fine. If your pip and pip3 are same then just `pip install mysqlclient` - normally pip is for Python2 and pip3 is for Python3

Comment: It seems to show that it's installed this way. I get 'Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in ...'file location' '

Comment: Then you need to verify you run Django in the same Python3 and not any other virtual environment. If your Django is run with different Python than it will not find it. You can always uprade if you want with `pip3 install mysqlclient --upgrade`. When you're running Django you should be using same Python3.

Comment: I ran that command and got confirmation it is already up-to-date. Blahh wondering if something from the very beginning was installed incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like the Python3 you're checking with pip3 and Django's Python3 are not same.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that means... What would this entail doing? Appreciate your help.

Comment: That means that at your machine you have more than a single Python. You may resort to getting mysqlclient into your local git repo and running `python3 setup.py install`. You have more than single Python3 at your machine, so verify which one is used where. A vm can have more than one Python3. There's no match between your `pip3` and the Python3 environment used with your Django. You'll know it's there once you'll be able to import it in Django shell.